# How can I get tsc to emit javascript source files in a composite monorepo?

Tags: typescript

Imagine a project with the following structure:

`tsconfig.json
packages
  |-app1
  | |-src
  |   |- file.d.ts
  |   |- file.js
  |   |- tsconfig.json`

The top-level `tsconfig.json` has the following:

`{
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./packages/app1/src"
    },
    ...
  ]
}`

And the nested package has a `tsconfig.json` with the following:

`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "composite": true,
    "declarationMap": true
  }
}`

I can run `tsc --build --watch` at the top level and have all my projects type-checked and built. The problem is that `file.js` will not be emitted by typescript because it is not a typescript file. In fact, it is a generated file (a gRPC stub) and typescript will fail if `allowJs: true` along-side `composite: true`.

This means that:

1. While iterating, the gRPC generated files will not be emitted.
2. While building (in docker), the gRPC generated files will also not be emitted.

Any ideas for getting `tsc` to emit the generated javascript files?

Comment: Hum perhaps this is not needed as the JS file itself already exist and seems to be resolved nicely. Maybe this should be handled at the bundler lever (whether it is webpack or something else). If you need the file for say running `jest` tests (using a custom transform option for your typescript files) it can also be handled at the `jest` configuration level. I'll try and look into it.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your suggestions. I should clarify that there is no bundler or jest involved and that this is server-side code.

Comment: Ok, so IIUC at some point you actually need to have all your files colocated for this to work properly ?

Comment: @adz5A that's a good point. I've actually pulled these autogenerated files into a separate directory. It is a shame to have to do this simply to assuage the limitations of the tools but this has returned me to productive workflow.